# Error with map and string conversion in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, key

I'm familiar with Python's dictionary function, and I'm assuming based on my research that C++'s map function is relatively similar. However I'm running into a "conversion" issue:

```
std::string dictionary(std::string inquiry){
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mapK;
        mapK["12th st. Oakland City Center"]="12th";
        mapK["16th st. Mission"]="16th";

    return mapK.find(inquiry);
}
```

This is a string function that should receive a string and then with the corresponding key return a string back to the main. Evidently there's an issue with the return statement.

```
error: could not convert 'mapK.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > > >((*(const key_type*)(& inquiry)))' from 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >}' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'
  return mapK.find(inquiry);
```

Comment: Seems you should use `std::string` instead of `std::basic_string`.

Comment: Should be map, Let me correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::map::find()` returns iterator, specifically `std::map::iterator`.

The only thing you need to fix is to put a dereference:

```
return *mapK.find(inquiry);
```

Or even better, just use `operator[]`:

```
return mapK[inquiry];
```

Do note though that if `inquiry` is not in the map, it will return empty string. In case of find, it is straight undefined behavior.

Comment: Odd, I thought I used mapk[inquiry] prior and it didn't work but its work now. Perhaps a typo. Thanks for the explanation on the dereference.

Comment: @Owen, be careful, if it doesn't the right element it will try to dereference end iterator, which is UB. I recommend putting a check and then returning default value.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the return type of `find`. It does not return the mapped type. Rather it returns an iterator.

The signature for find is `iterator find( const Key& key );` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find); there is also the const overload).

You should also check whether the key was found. So you could write something like

```
MapType::iterator i = mapK.find(inquiry);
if (i != mapK.end())
    return i->second;
else
    return ""; // or handle error some other way
```

Alternatively you could use the member access `operator[]`, but this will insert a default constructed element in the map if the key is not found.